# Scripting library for the Compact Framework

Tags: c#, scripting, compact-framework, windows-ce

Does anyone know if there is a scripting library for the .Net Compact Framework 2.0 (WinCE 5) available?
Something like Iron Python, or LUA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At Lua site there are notes about Lua is portable to Pocket PC platform ( http://www.lua.org/about.html), but it seems there are no compiled binaries for that platform.

Also quick googling give me S# project: http://www.orbifold.net/default/?p=2457
The support of .NET Compact Framework is declared, but I don't work with that library before, so can't provide you any information about.

Answer (score 0):

DO you mean something like [Tcl](http://www.evolane.com/software/etcl/), [Ruby](http://www.infoq.com/news/2008/12/rhodes-iphone-winmobile-rim), [Perl](http://perlce.sourceforge.net/), [Lua](http://luaforge.net/projects/lua4wince/), or [Python](http://pythonce.sourceforge.net/Wikka/HomePage)?

Comment: Yes, but I need one which can interact with my managed code. So that a CF program can be extend with plugins, without the need of recompile anything.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a plugin architecture for Compact Framework, then there is a CF MEF port which I can highly recommend.

http://pocketmef.codeplex.com